# Many to Many Filtering in Jquery by checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me to filter the data with multiple select fields simultaneously like many other filtering widgets? Though the following code is working good when select fields are not multiple, I would like to have the select fields multiple so users can filter the data for multiple values from a single field.

```js
        //call the same function for each select's change event
        $("select.bedrooms, select.floors").change(updateProps);
        
        function updateProps() {
          //get all the values
            var propBedrooms = $('select.bedrooms').val();
            var propFloors = $('select.floors').val();
            
          $('.filter-container-data')
            .find('.single-property-box')
            .hide()
            .filter(function () {

              var okPropBedrooms = true;
              if(propBedrooms !== "all"){
                okPropBedrooms = $(this).attr('data-bedrooms') === propBedrooms;
              }

              var okPropFloors = true;
              if(propFloors !== "all"){
                okPropFloors = $(this).attr('data-floor') === propFloors;
              }
              
              //only fade a room if it satisfies all conditions
              return okPropBedrooms && okPropFloors;
          }).fadeIn('fast');
        }
```

```css
.single-property-box {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="custom-filters">
  <select multiple class="bedrooms">
    <option value="all">Bedrooms</option>
    <option value="1bd">1</option>
    <option value="2bd">2</option>
    <option value="3bd">3</option>
  </select>
                        
  <select multiple class="floors">
    <option value="all">Floors</option>
    <option value="1flr">1</option>
    <option value="2flr">2</option>
    <option value="3flr">3</option>
  </select>         
</div>

<div class="filter-container-data">
  <div class="single-property-box" data-bedrooms="1bd" data-floor="1flr">1 Bedroom, 1 Floor</div>
  <div class="single-property-box" data-bedrooms="1bd" data-floor="2flr">1 Bedroom, 2 Floor</div>
  <div class="single-property-box" data-bedrooms="1bd" data-floor="3flr">1 Bedroom, 3 Floor</div>
  <div class="single-property-box" data-bedrooms="2bd" data-floor="1flr">2 Bedroom, 1 Floor</div>
  <div class="single-property-box" data-bedrooms="2bd" data-floor="2flr">2 Bedroom, 2 Floor</div>
  <div class="single-property-box" data-bedrooms="2bd" data-floor="3flr">2 Bedroom, 3 Floor</div>
  <div class="single-property-box" data-bedrooms="3bd" data-floor="1flr">3 Bedroom, 1 Floor</div>
  <div class="single-property-box" data-bedrooms="3bd" data-floor="2flr">3 Bedroom, 2 Floor</div>
  <div class="single-property-box" data-bedrooms="3bd" data-floor="3flr">3 Bedroom, 3 Floor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter table rows with multiple filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080469/filter-table-rows-with-multiple-filters)

Comment: @Sercan No, I am looking for multiple values. For single select value, the above code works like a charm,